# App-only token - Microsoft Graph - Preferred language

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

we are facing an issue while requesting Microsoft Graph to get information from SharePoint Comms Site.
That particular site has multilanguage activated and the site title is translated.
We have an Azure function that is using a registered app to consume Graph.

When we are doing this request to Graph
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/:/sites/test-comms-site. The site title returned is not the English one, but the translated.
Is there any way to configure the registered app or azure function, ... to force a "Preferred-Language"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, currently, you cannot set 'Preferred-Language' on a multilanguage activate SharePoint site.

Being said that, consider filing [UserVoice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask so that it could be considered for future implementations.

Comment: Thanks, 
this is not documented any place, but managed to get the site in the proper language, using the Accept-Language header

$Headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($access_token)"
    'Accept-Language' = 'en-US'
}

$ResultSite = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/XXXX.sharepoint.com/:/sites/CPTestIssue1659EnglishUpd' -Headers $Headers